# Android and Drupal login system

Tags: android, drupal, authentication

I'm in the middle of developing an Android app, and in this app I want the user to login or register a new account. The way I want to have the login system to be, is that the app contacts my Drupal website and (the site has the module called Janrain Engage) get the information from there and compare it with the input of EditText.

I have searched around the web to find a solution, but without any luck. I have also tried sample from Janrain Engage own site.

I would be happy if anyone could give me an example how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I've used the [DrupalCloud](https://github.com/INsReady/DrupalCloud) library for a couple of projects and it worked well. It works together with the [Services](http://drupal.org/project/services) module.

Services exposes a couple of webservices for the user such as registration and authentication. I didn't work with the Janrain module so I don't know if the user services will be aware of it. If they aren't you might have to write your own service that checks the data from Janrain.